# undefined is not an object evaluating ('_this.state') Error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever I resolve this problem a new issue arises like Can't find variable: `state` ,
so what's happening here? actually, I made a screen where I'm using  `onPress={()=>this.saveitem()}` on a button and on the other hand declaring state variable in below Class,
export default class  App extends `React.Component {} ...` I imported that specific component but in vain ... help me out brothers... enter code here

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  state={
    text:"",
    mylist:[]
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe `state = { ... }` should be `this.state = { ... }`

Comment: tried `this.state=` in your `constructor`, instead of  `state=`

Comment: Brothers i put it after your guidance but it didn't work so now ?